# Creating Javascript prototypes for built-in objects within a namespace

Tags: javascript, object, namespaces, prototype

Is it possible to create prototypes for built-in objects inside of a specific namespace as to avoid collisions with coexisting code?

Example, say I have this prototype:

```
// prototype to be run against native objects
Object.prototype.getSomeInfo = function() {
    // do stuff with object
}
```

But what if `getSomeInfo` is an existing method within some coexisting code?

Is it possible to do something where I can call it as `someObject.myCustomLibrary.getSomeInto()`?

Comment: Object is native, but better to call it [**built–in**](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.7). Augmenting Object.prototype is considered bad form because it complicates *for..in* enumeration, though *for..in* should guard against that anyway.

Comment: "But what if getSomeInfo is an existing prototype…" I think you mean method.

Comment: @RobG: thanks, I wasn't sure I had the right terminology.  Question edited.

Comment: That's exactly one of the reasons why extending the prototype of built-in objects is not a good idea.

Comment: @FelixKling: I've read varying opinions on this.  What attracts me to it is maintaining the Javascript `Object.method` conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've taken FelixKing's advice and just moved everything to non-prototyped functions.

Now I can call them as `myLibrary.someCategory.function(myObject, param, param, ...)`